# How to setup an oracle in Vyper?

Tags: solidity, oracles, vyper

I need an ETH-USD price oracle for my vyper contract. So far, the oracle services I've found, like chainlink, are written in solidity. Is it possible to use a solidity oracle in a vyper contract? How can I do this?

Would I have to build my own oracle?

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the oracle contract interfaces in Vyper, then call them like you would any other contract: https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/structure-of-a-contract.html#contract-interfaces